# Clase Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function agregarStringInvertida() {
  String.prototype.reverse = function (){
    let newString = '';
    for(let x=this.length-1;x>=0;x--){
      newString = newString + this.charAt(x);
    }
    return newString;
  }
}
```

Alguien me podría explicar la lógica del for? Y tambien en la parte de `this.charAt(x)`?
Porque me lo dieron de tarea, y lo terminé copiando del repositorio con las respuestas, pero no puedo entender como llegar a ese código por mi propia cuenta

Desde ya muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 6):

Como se usa un prototipo, `this`, representa el string recibido. Por ejemplo

```js
String.prototype.any = function() {
    console.log(this);
}
```

**IMPORTANTE**: `this` **NO** Funcionará si el prototipo tiene una **[función flecha](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)**, pues como se especifica, estas no tienen contexto y `this` será `window`

Si usamos este prototipo, por ejemplo en un string así

```js
"hola".any()
// Salida: "hola"
```

Ahora bien, el `for` lo que hace es recorrer el string desde su último carácter hasta el primero, recuerda que en JavaScript, los índices empiezan desde 0 y terminan en el largo del objeto - 1

Por ejemplo, usando este string: `"abc"`, la salida sería `"cba"`

Va así:

- El bucle obtiene el largo del string (3) y le resta 1 => 2
- Va recorriendo desde el índice 2 hasta el índice 0 (Ir recorriendo desde derecha hacia izquiera)
- Va concatenando otro string con la letra que se obtiene con el bucle, que será el string invertido
- Devuelve el nuevo string

El método `charAt`, devuelve la letra que está en esa posición del string, en el caso del string anterior, la posición 2 será "c"

Analicemos la estructura del `for`:

```js
for(let x=this.length-1;x>=0;x--)
```

Lo que está haciendo es definir una variable con los tres primeros puntos de antes.

Ahora, recordando los operadores aritméticos, tenemos

- `++` => Aumento (+1)
- `--` => Decremento (-1)

Tiene lógica, pues va desde el último carácter del string hasta el primero, es decir, en nuestro string de ejemplo, irá recorriendo desde la posición 2 hasta la posición 0, como se usa el operador `--`, se decrementa el índice en 1 hasta llegar al 0

Aunque podrías haber simplificado el código mucho más con usar los corchetes para obtener índice que quieres

```js
"abc"[2] // "c";
// Igual a: "abc".charAt(2)
```

Referencia:

- [`String.prototype.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)
- [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)
- [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)